# Sharepoint web application down when iis in one SP server is down

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a SP farm in which I have 2 SP servers linked to a single DB server. The Web application is up when IIS service in both the servers are running. I stopped the 1st SP server IIS service, while IIS service was running in the 2nd and again found that the web application is up. I stopped the IIS service in 2nd server and started the IIS service in the 1st, then I found that the Web Application is not working. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

How you added both of these servers in to the sharepoint farm ? By running the SharePoint Product Configuration wizard?

If you try to add your new server as wfe then it should be taken care by the configuration wizard

Comment: I added the new server to the same farm using configuration wizard and both are made wfe.